# Finding the default browser in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am using Process.Start(url) to launch a URL in the default web browser and then I plan to close it using Process.Kill().

The problem is finding the default browser to know which process to kill. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: [Opening default web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562183/opening-default-web-browser)

```
Private Function getDefaultBrowser() As String
    Dim browser As String = String.Empty
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Nothing
    Try
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("HTTP\shell\open\command", False)

        'trim off quotes
        browser = key.GetValue(Nothing).ToString().ToLower().Replace("""", "")
        If Not browser.EndsWith("exe") Then
            'get rid of everything after the ".exe"
            browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4)
        End If
    Finally
        If key IsNot Nothing Then
            key.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return browser
End Function
```

There you can get the default browser. Then you can loop through the running process and kill the browser.

```
Dim browser As String
browser = getDefaultBrowser()
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses        
    If p.ProcessName = browser Then
        p.Kill()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: For the kill to work I had to strip "browser" down with:

    browserp = IO.Path.GetFileName(browser)
    strfile = browserp
    Dim strSplit() As String
    strSplit = Split(strFile, ".")
    browserkill = (strSplit(0))

Thin replace browser with broweserkill. I'm sure there is a more elegant way but it works.